# Draw ink on 2 inkCanvases at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

I am implementing multi-touch application. I have 2 inkcanvases that EditingMode is "Ink".
If I draw ink on 2 inkcanvases at the same time, it 's not working. I can draw ink on only one inkcanvas at a time.

```
 <Grid x:Name="g1">
        <InkCanvas Background="CadetBlue" Margin="0,0,153,0" EditingMode="Ink"></InkCanvas>
        <InkCanvas Background="Red" Margin="153,0,20,0" EditingMode="Ink"></InkCanvas>
    </Grid>
```

How do I draw ink on 2 inkcanvases at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only draw on one Canvas at a time. You can try drawing little bit by bit on both alternatively so that it may look like being drawn simultaneously.